# Ошибка _apt no sandbox , как исправить?

Tags: linux, termux

Как это исправить :

```
dpkg: error processing package gvfs-fuse (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udisks2
 geoclue-2.0
 pulseaudio
 gvfs-daemons
 gvfs-backends
 gnome-disk-utility
 lightdm
 gvfs:arm64
 light-locker
 gvfs-fuse
W: No sandbox user '_apt' on the system, can not drop privileges
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Спасибо ...

Comment: No sandbox user - это ерунда, не влияет. у тебя проблемы с зависимостями

Comment: Да , спасибо ...

Comment: Решил проблему так : снёс Debian и поставил ArchLinux ... Она стабильнее ...